# Python send a JSON Array via POST

Tags: python, json, rest, csv, post

I am trying to create a python script that does the following:

- Parse a CSV file
- Send the CSV file to a remote server via REST API

The code I have is working to parse the CSV file and convert it to a JSON object.

However, when it imports to the remote server, only the first row is written.

Question: Do I need to loop through and send a SEPARATE http request for EACH ROW? I feel like that would be too cumbersome. My CSV file has over 10,000 rows and this will be running on a daily cron.

Question: How can I set this up to import all rows in a single request?

```
#Requests package for python import requests
import csv
import json
import requests

#Parse CSV file and convert to JSON

f = open('example_import_csv.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames = ("u_date","u_product","u_serial_number"))
out = json.dumps([row for row in reader])
#Print output confirms that the JSON is formatted properly
print(">JSON" , out) 

#Set request parameters
url = 'xxxxx'
user = 'xxxxxx'
pwd = 'xxxxxx'

#Set proper headers
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

#data=out contains the JSON object
#Problem is only the first row is imported
response = requests.post(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers ,data=out)

#Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers)
    exit()

#Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
print('Status:',response.status_code,'Headers:',response.headers,'Response:',response.json())


### OUTPUT

# >JSON [{"u_serial_number": "11", "u_product": "Apples", "u_date": "1/12/15"}, {"u_serial_number": "12", "u_product": "Pears", "u_date": "1/29/15"}, {"u_serial_number": "13", "u_product": "Oranges", "u_date": "1/12/15"}, {"u_serial_number": "14", "u_product": "Blackberries", "u_date": "1/29/15"}, {"u_serial_number": "15", "u_product": "Blueberries", "u_date": "2/5/15"}, {"u_serial_number": "16", "u_product": "Bananas", "u_date": "2/7/15"}, {"u_serial_number": "17", "u_product": "Strawberries", "u_date": "2/7/15"}]

# Status: 201 Headers: {'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

EDIT: I am sending the data to our ServiceNow instance. Here is a wiki article which describes the python script template.

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API_Python_Examples#gsc.tab=0

Here's the basic code block that I used as a template. Note that this works for a single row of data as per the example but doest not work when importing multiple rows of data.

```
#Need to install requests package for python
 #sudo easy_install requests
 import requests

 # Set the request parameters
 url = 'https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident'
 user = 'xxxxxxx'
 pwd = 'xxxxxxx'

 # Set proper headers
 headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

 # Do the HTTP request
 response = requests.post(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers ,data='{"short_description":"Test"}')

 # Check for HTTP codes other than 200
 if response.status_code != 201: 
     print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:',response.json())
     exit()
```

Comment: Surely the problem is with whatever is processing the post on the remote server?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I think you are onto something here. I tested this out by using the REST API Explorer (a graphical UI to generate requests)  in ServiceNow. Sure enough, only one of the records went through. I think there might be a limitation in ServiceNow where it can only accept one record per request. I will post in the vendor specific section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that the ServiceNow REST API can only allow one record per request.

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API#POST_.2Fapi.2Fnow.2Fv1.2Ftable.2F.28tableName.29

I have switched to the JSONv2 API to insert multiple records.
http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=JSONv2_Web_Service#insert

Thanks to Daniel who helped point me in the right direction with my troubleshooting.